# How to get continous number from number squence when import BOM via AIF web service - AX 2012

Tags: xml, web-services, dynamics-ax-2012, aif, number-sequence

I would like to import BOM over the standard BOM AIF Web Service in AX 2012.

In my XML-File I don't define any BOMId, because the system should take the next possible BOMId from the existing number sequence.

[image: XML-File]

When I start the import of my XML-File I get the following error message.

[image: Exception]

This is the setting of my number sequence.

[image: Number Sequence]

What do I have to do to automatically get the next available number from the number sequence (Continous), when importing BOMs via the standard AX AIF Web Service?

Comment: What about excluding the BomId from the XML altogether.  As it is, it is still being specified - as blank.

Comment: If I remove the whoe BOMId-Tag from the XML, I get an error that the BOMId-Tag is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the cross references of the exception message (label id @SYS96663, btw) to method `checkNumber` of class `AxInternalBase`, which calls method `numAllowEdit` of table `NumberSequenceTable`. From the logic of that method it seems that one of the checkboxes "Manual", "To a lower number" or "To a higher number" needs to be set for this to work. Not sure why, though or which of the checkboxes is the right one or makes the most sense. My gut tells me to go with "To a higher number", but [ymmv](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary).

Also take a look at the related question [Dynamics AX 2012 R3 - Record Creation through AIF web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661658/dynamics-ax-2012-r3-record-creation-through-aif-web-service) and method `setBOMId` of class `AxBOMTable`.